# Websoket extension for Laravel5.1?

Tags: laravel, websocket

I want developing programs like QQ or MSN, i will use websocket and laravel5.1.

so,is there some extension to use websocket for laravel5.1? I just know

Comment: When using websockets and Laravel you don't really need an extension specific for laravel. You can integrate the websocket very easy inside the frontend of you application just by inserting a javascript file. Server side is a little more complicated since you will need to use something like Node.js. However it is very easy to setup something like this. Check [this](http://socket.io/).

Comment: First,thanks for your answer. I know use Node.js,but my boss just use php,so i must use websocket and laravel. I know swoole and hoa/websocket, but I don't know which is to use them.

Comment: You should use the Redis subscriber functions, and socket.io. Laracasts made a very good tutorial on how to integrate it with Laravel: https://laracasts.com/series/real-time-laravel-with-socket-io/episodes/1